# How to add command to Linux shell after we open it from window command prompt?

Tags: java

I want to access linux shell and put command into it from my CMD(command prompt) windows.

Below is my code to open linux shell from cmd.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", "accessLinux.bat"});
```

I have try putting command after accessLinux.bat, but the compiler will join my accesLinux.bat and argument1 as one statement instead of treat it seperately eventhough i have put double quote.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", "\""accessLinux.bat argument1 + "\""});
```

below is my accesslinux.bat

```
@echo off
set PATH=C:\;%PATH%
set CYGWIN=binmode tty
set TERM=ansi
set USERNAME=user
set HOME=C:\
set RSYNC_RSH=ssh.exe
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@address  %1
```

Comment: That's all contextual.  Does that `accessLinux.bat` take arguments?  In any case, you are always better off using `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, it does take argument but the idea is i have to open linux shell(debian terminal) from cmd and then java will put command into that linux shell. example, mkdir file1.

from my reading and little knowledge currently i can only put command to to the cmd . got lost on how i can put command to linux shell after i open it from cmd

Comment: Then you `exec` command should look more like `{"cmd", "/c", "start", "accessLinux.bat", argument1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on MadProgramer comment

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", accessLinux.bat,  argument1});
```